# How to make a rigidbody on a curved plane?

Tags: physics, rigidbody

I used [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-ab0fjwqWQ) video to create a curved plane and then made a UV sphere. My plane is curved smoothly. However, when I try to give it a rigidbody and let the sphere slide on it, it acts as though the rigidbody was where the flat plane would be instead of the curved surface. How do I fix this?

Edit: I am using convex hull, and have attached a screenshot.
[image: Blender Image]

Other Edit: Thank you so much! It worked!

Comment: Please add screenshots to clarify the problem.

Comment: Without any information on your rigid body settings or screenshots of those settings, this is just blindly guessing: is the curved plane set to the default collision shape "Convex Hull"? Then the concave side of your plane will be treated as a flat plane - because that's as close as a convex hull can get on a concave surface. You have to switch to "Mesh".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ground, in the *Physics* panel, choose *Shape > Mesh, Source > Deform*:

[image]

[image]